# Efficient Algorithm for computing the largest entry in the matrix $(D+CC^T)^{-1}$ where $C \in R^{n \times r}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Suppose $D = diag(d_1,...,d_n)$ with $d_i > 0$ for all $i$. Give an efficient algorithm for computing the largest entry in the matrix $(D+CC^T)^{-1}$ where $C \in R^{n \times r}$. Hint: Use the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula.

---

I have tried several examples and it seems that $(D+CC^T)^{-1}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix but I can't prove that. Maybe it is not S.P.D. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D$ is diagonal with positive diagonal entries, it is positive semi definite, and
so is $D+C^TC$.  It is an elementary fact that the inverse of a psd matrix is psd.  (You can verify this last fact by diagonalization:  if $A$ is psd, then $A=O\Lambda O^T$ where $O$ is orthogonal and $\Lambda$ is diagonal with positive entries, so $A^{-1} = O \Lambda^{-1} O^T$, etc.)

Comment: You are right. Since $D + CC^T$ is S.P.D., its inverse is also S.P.D. because the eigenvalue of the inverse is the reciprocal of the eigenvalue of the original matrix. The hint for Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula makes it complicated.